# My sqlite does not work show java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android

here show  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo error and virtual device shows

**Gennymotion device**

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.somiron.sqlight;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText e1,e2,e3,e4;
    Button b;
    mysqlite my;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        e3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        e4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        my = new mysqlite(this);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                my.addtotable(e1.getText().toString(),e2.getText().toString(),e3.getText().toString(),e4.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**mysqlite.java**

```
package com.example.somiron.sqlight;;

public class mysqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DATA.DB";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "PER_INFO";
    private static final String COLUMN1 = "ID";
    private static final String COLUMN2 = "FIRSTNAME";
    private static final String COLUMN3 = "LASTNAME";
    private static final String COLUMN4 = "EMAIL";

    public mysqlite(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      // db = new SQLiteDatabase();
        db.isOpen();
        String query;
        query = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"(" +COLUMN1+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +COLUMN2+ " TEXT, " +COLUMN3+ " TEXT, " +COLUMN4+ " TEXT "+ ")";
       db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }



    public void addtotable(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3) {

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN1,s);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN2,s1);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN3,s2);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN4,s3);
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    }
}
```

Comment: please add crash log

Comment: just a side comment - is there any specific reason ta name your variables that way? `COLUMN1`, `s1` etc... would be much more readable to have `COL_ID = "ID"` instead

Comment: where are you initiating your database?

Answer (score 0):

1) Change class name to `MySqlite` instead of `mysqlite`

http://www.iwombat.com/standards/JavaStyleGuide.html#Class%20and%20Interface%20Names

2) Fetch your values from database. According to your code, you just put data in database, but did not read them from it.
It can be used `Cursor` for it. Create in `MySqlite` proper method, say, `readData()` or with an other name you like.

3) Create in `MainActivity` `String` values and assign to them proper values from your database with `getString()` and `getColumnIndex()`.

4) Put those assigned values to proper `EditText` with `setText()`.

These are basic things you should do to make your code alive.

But, all in all, before working with sqlite, please, read some articles and tuts:

http://codetheory.in/working-sqlite-database-crud-operations-android/

http://www.journaldev.com/9438/android-sqlite-database-example-tutorial

http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-sqlite-database-tutorial

I think it will help you.